# Message Durability in MassTransit/RabbitMQ

Tags: .net, rabbitmq, masstransit

I have 2 applications, an event publishing one and an event consumer one.
The publishing one uses SimpleInjector:

```
container.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.AddBus(() => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
    {
        var host = cfg.Host(ConfigurationValuesProvider.Current.Get("RabbitHostName"), hostConfigurator =>
        {

        });

    }));
});
```

The consumer one uses CastleWindsor:

```
container.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.AddBus(context => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
    {
        var host = cfg.Host(configurationProvider.RabbitHostName);

        x.AddConsumer<FactAddedHandler>();
        x.AddConsumer<FactAddedWebhookHandler>();
        x.AddConsumer<FactMonitorHandler>();

        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(container);
    }));

});
```

Everything works fine, altough I tried to make some of the messages I publish non-durable by putting in the **consumer** registration:

```
x.AddConsumer<FactAddedHandler>().Endpoint(e =>
{
    e.Temporary = true;
});
```

In this way the queue is marked as temporary and will be deleted as soon as the application goes down. But I only want the messages to be non durable, I would like the queue to be still up and ready when the application goes down. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by 'non-durable'? You can use RMQ policies to enforce a message TTL, for example (meaning messages which are not consumed after X seconds will be removed from the queue).

Comment: for non-durable I mean not persisted on the disk. Meaning that if they are in queue and RabbitMQ goes down by any chance, they need to do NOT need to be saved on the disk. So when RabbitMQ goes up again, they are lost and none cares

Comment: You should create a consumer definition and override the configure method to access the receive endpoint configurator. https://masstransit-project.com/usage/containers/#definition

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, I don't think `e.Temporary = true;` is doing what you think it'll do.

When configuring your endpoints, the configurator passed to the configuration function is a fairly general cross-broker `IReceiveEndpointConfigurator`. If you want to configure some broker-specific stuff, you can cast to a broker-specific configurator. For example, for RMQ:

```cs
x.AddConsumer<FactAddedHandler>().Endpoint("my_queue", e =>
{
  if (e is IRabbitMqReceiveEndpointConfigurator r)
  {
    r.Durable = false;
  }
});
```

Note that if you don't specify a queue name there, you're going to end up with an MT "temporary queue" anyway, which will be named uniquely and destroyed when your application shuts down. That may not be what you want.

Comment: Mmmm.. to be honest that's not what is happening. First of all when I do not specify the name the queue will not be destroyed. I just tried by shutting down the consumer application, the publisher application and also RabbitMQ. All queues persist and I didn't specify the name in any of them but they get created with an unique name decided by MT/RabbitMQ. Second: I tried your solution. The queue in that is not marked for auto-delete anymore luckily, but the message is still durable and persisted